# Localhost on mac doesn't work / Server can't connect / 404 Not found / 403 Forbidden

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, localhost

Localhost says - It works, but these Localhost/phpmyadmin and localhost/~username:

> Safari Can't connect with Server

I don't use MAMP. I installed additionally MySQL and I downloaded Phpmyadmin and placed this folder to Sites.

my httpd-vhosts.confg has

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/bereshka/Sites/parustrans"
    ServerName parustrans.local
</VirtualHost>
```

my hosts has

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 parustrans.local
my users/bereshka.conf has

<Directory "/Users/bereshka/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my httpd.confg has

Comment: my httpd-vhosts.confg has

Comment: You question is not very clear, and is likely to be put on hold in its present state. In general if `http://localhost` works then the other two addresses (still on `http://localhost/`) should do _something_. What does "doesn't work" mean - do you get 404 errors?

Comment: Please read the help section on how to use this site. This is not a forum, you don’t post more information on *answers*. You create one question and include all information on it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I edited that

Comment: @halfer I think I messed up apache or/and hosts. These two links localhost/phpmyadmin and localhost/~bereshka/ show this error Safari Can't connect with Server

Comment: @hajfer I just replaced the code in httpd.confg , httpd-vhosts.confg , hosts, username.confg to the code from the same files, but of other mac, where has never been done any works with apache. And now Server can connect, but I still get an error, but other kind Localhost/phpmyadmin and localhost/~username  - 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution myself. Want to share it with all who face the same. Steps that I did:

1. I replaced the code in httpd.confg , httpd-vhosts.confg , hosts, username.confg to the code from the same files, but of other mac, where has never been done any works with apache. Because for last few days I was editing all that so many times and I already lost the hope to fix it)) It let me to start all from zero. This step solved the problem "Safari Can't connect with Server" , but other error appeared when I go by localhost/~username I get 404 Not Found
2. I uncommented these lines in httpd.confg

   LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
   LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
   LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
   LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
   LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
   LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

check this [article](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) for detailed description of all steps

3. But this action (in my case) returned again this error - "Server cannot connect.." . I found under above mentioned article in comments that it might be solved if to comment back this line -  LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so and I did that (I'm on mac Sierra 10.12.6)
4. That helped )) but when I checked localhost/~username I got a new error 403 Forbidden by link localhost/~username. But when I typed only localhost - It works.
5. It's obviously problems with permissions and user. So I checked my two files username.conf and bereshka.conf in the folder apache2/users and I set this code (for Apache 2.4) instead of all what was there (/Users/bereshka/Sites/ accordingly)

   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted

this one doesn't work

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

It's for apache 2.2

6. Now I can see the list of folders in Sites, next task is to install Joomla, but it's another story :)